# How to get an array from memcache | PHP

Tags: php, arrays, memcached

I have a little problem with memcache.

My code:

```
$var_key = $memcache->get($_POST['link']);
if(empty($var_key)) {
    foreach($var_key as $value) {
        $result['link_download'] = $value['link_download']; // doens't work
        $result['discription'] = $value; // it works
    }
}
else {
    foreach($html->find('.class') as $value) {
        $result['link_download'] = pq($value)->find('a:eq(1)')->attr('href');
        $result['discription'] = pq($value)->find('tr:eq(0) > td:eq(1)')->html(); 
    }
}

if(empty($var_key)) {
    $memcache->replace($_POST['link'], $result); 
    $memcache->set($_POST['link'], $result, false, 1*60);
}
```

Why `$value['link_download']` or `$value['discription']` doesn't work, but just `$value` works perfectly?

Comment: var_dump($var_key), than you (perhaps) shed some light on it.

Comment: See "/* foreach example 4: multi-dimensional arrays */" given here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php ... which you should have, that your foreach works like it is currently.

Comment: @djot, var_dump: array(2) { ["link_download"]=> string(34) "http://d.rutor.org/download/307273" ["discription"]=> string(3712) "

Comment: And what does that mean? `$value` is alway the `['xy']` part, as `string`, not `array`.

Comment: @djot, Now I understand, but what to do?

Answer (score 0):

ugly, but works

```
$var_key = $memcache->get($_POST['link']);
$var_key = array(0=>$var_key);

if (is_array($var_key[0]) AND count($var_key[0]) > 0) {
...
```

... so not really recommended, just a fix to use the code you currently have without many changes!

... and the justification for this code above is given in my comments (for those of you who can't read).